# local storage problem when trying to fetch data from localstorage using useEffect() in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to fetch data in localstorage using ReactJS. Can some one please help me here is my sample code.

```
let [rows,setRows] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        rows = localStorage.getItem("my_tier_list");
        if(rows){
            setRows(JSON.parse(rows));
        }
  
      },[]);
  
      React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("my_tier_list", JSON.stringify(cart));
      });
```

**Can some one please help me and thanks in advance**

Comment: Can some one please help me?

Comment: Please don't repost questions! We had it already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817556/preserved-on-page-refresh-in-reactjs

Comment: What should be stored in local storage? A list? object?

Comment: Why are you ignoring my question and just ask for help again?

Comment: @Igot => It's not working the other gave answer similar to you. But couldn't working

Comment: I asked you what should be stored? List? Object? What kind of structure? Please show code you have so far (minified)

Comment: When i clk on the add to cart, It should store the all the details about the product. You can see this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-shamir-m0kx4k?file=/src/Header.js . If require you can download this and run it on your system :)

Comment: Btw just saying - if you building an e commerce site, you should persist your cart data in a database, not localStorage

Comment: @Igr => why am i trying to save data in a localstorage is, when i refresh browser, The cart data should be available after refresh too

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems to your above code.

1. You can't directly assign values to your state variable using `=`, you must do it using the setter functions.
2. You have not added the dependency list in the second `useEffect`.
3. You have not used the correct name to set the localStorage.

```
let [rows,setRows] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // you can't directly set a state variable. Create a new local variable
        const localRows = localStorage.getItem("my_tier_list");
        if(localRows){
            setRows(JSON.parse(localRows));
        }
  
      },[]);
  
      React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("my_tier_list", JSON.stringify(rows)); // corrected it to rows
      }, [rows]); // added the array as dependency list. This will trigger this only when "rows" gets changed
```

### Update

Based on your code shared through code sandbox, you need to update your Reducer.js.

```
const updateLocalStorage = (cart) => {
  localStorage.setItem("my_tier_list", JSON.stringify(cart));
};
export const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART": {
      const updatedState = {
        ...state,
        cart: [...state.cart, { ...action.payload, qty: 1 }]
      };
      updateLocalStorage(updatedState.cart);
      return updatedState;
    }
    case "REMOVE_FROM_CART": {
      const updatedState = {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter((c) => c.id !== action.payload.id)
      };
      updateLocalStorage(updatedState.cart);
      return updatedState;
    }
    case "CHANGE_CART_QTY": {
      const updatedState = {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter((c) =>
          c.id === action.payload.id ? (c.qty = action.payload.qty) : c.qty
        )
      };
      updateLocalStorage(updatedState.cart);
      return updatedState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And in Header.js

```
    let [rows,setRows] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const localRows = localStorage.getItem("my_tier_list");
        if(localRows){
            setRows(JSON.parse(localRows));
        }
      },[cart]); // adding cart will ensure any changes you make is reflected.
```

Comment: => Can you please help me, I will share the code sandboxlink with you

Comment: I have already posted the corrected code (with comments) in my answer. Do you need any other help?

Comment: let me check first then by modifying my code then will come back to you :)

Comment: => I hope still facing the same problem let me share a code sandbox link. I am creating it now

Comment: could you please help me?

Comment: The codesandox is not loading. I tried multiple times.
Error: Could not fetch dependencies, please try again in a couple seconds:

Comment: let me look over it once

Comment: Here is the https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-shamir-m0kx4k?file=/src/SingleProduct.js

Comment: => Now it is working. Can you please help me it should be in a workable condition. https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-shamir-m0kx4k?file=/src/Header.js . It should also show the data in the cart as well in the header.

Comment: => I checked over it, I am getting null array. COuld you please help me?

Comment: The problem with your code is not in the Header.js. If you want to store all the information in localStorage, you must do it at the time of storing in the reducer state. And then fetch it in the Header.js. You don't need to set localStorage items from your header.js.

Comment: => I tried it, Can you please modify the code in a sandbox, because I tried in localhost. But couldn't work.

Comment: you are free to edit my code, I don't mind but make it workable

Comment: Can you please help me?I am trying in different ways but not working out

Answer (score 0):

Please look into following sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-rain-n97hf3

- Set local storage item on some event handler: `localStorage.setItem("value", value);`
- Get local storage item with: `const localStorageValue = localStorage.getItem("value");`

Comment: => But in my case, It is complety a bit different. Could you please help?. I am writing a cart application. When I clk on the button it should store in localstorage and when I refresh as well it should be available in cart and thanks for sharing the StackOverflow link. I think code is similar a bit. If require I can share my code sandbox link?